# Is there a naming convention for database tables created by a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, database

I have setup my plugin's table to use $wpdb->prefix but aside from that are there any conventions that you should name them;

Maybe `$wpdb->prefix.'plugin_'.$tablename` or something.

I can't find any documentation and the examples of plugins I have used in the past don't seem to adhere to anything in particular.

Comment: You should use unique name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mohit, a unique name is required, the table wouldn't create properly if you didn't use a unique name.

Comment: No its created but if old table exists then it update with your new table so maybe few functionality, plugin or any theme stop working or maybe full functionality too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say (and that's just my *opinion*), that prefixing global available stuff like:

- functions
- classes
- tables
- ...

should always share the same prefix. Aside from making your code more unique & therefore collision save, it helps when searching for plugin code, plus it serves as branding for your plugin too. Adding `plugin_` to the table name seems like a valid and honorable idea, as it makes the Qs "Does it come from a theme, or a plugin? Where do I have to search for it?" obsolete.